# Library not found when building distribution config in xcode 4

Tags: xcode, configuration, build, build-process

I have a minor problem. Whenever I try to build my project using the distribution configuration it complains that one of my libraries is missing
`ld: library not found for -lTouchCustoms`
This only appears in distribution mode. The only difference between the release and distribution build is in the code signing section. Because of this I had to use the release build (with distribution profile code signing) to publish my app because that builds correctly, and was acceppted. If I delete and recreate the distribution config, duplicating the release config, I get the same error. How do I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the static library doesn't have the "distribution" build configuration. It will default to building the Release configuration instead. When the linker is trying to bring everything together, it is unfortunately looking in the "distribution-iphoneos" folder for the library while the library is actually in the "Release-iphoneos" library.

I'm trying to find a [general solution for this issue in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523690/xcode-custom-build-configuration-causes-library-file-not-found-for-static-libr). For you and others it should suffice to simply add the same configuration to all static libraries you're linking against as well.

Comment: This might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615102/specifying-a-subprojects-configuration-in-xcode?rq=1